# Unknown pointer glitch on my windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

Hi I am using windows 10 with wireless mouse and Recently I started facing this issue please check below link which shows video capture of the issue
https://streamable.com/5t3c0

Not sure what this issue is called but frustrates me to the highest point, it doesn't allow me to work with pointer being blinking in the circles

I contacted Microsoft help they ran some troubleshooting steps still issue is not solved, I tried resetting the laptop but still issues exists can anyone throw some light if anyone faced this kind of issue

Comment: The video shows booting while Windows is updating. What is the problem?

Comment: Please look closer there are white dots blinking all around

Comment: You mean the patches with light colors? I mistook them for a bad recording. I think that this cannot be any driver problem, but would rather go for hardware. You could add a secondary monitor, if the display adapter has an additional port, to see if the problem is with the adapter or the screen. A repair-shop may be more precise.

Comment: Ok thanks for inputs, i might have marked them but I don't much resources to edit the video will check the inputs